# jQuery Need Help Escaping Variables

Tags: jquery, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to combine these variables and append them to a select tag but the vars contain special characters and everything gets all jumbled up. No matter how I try to escape the special characters I can't get it to work. Can anyone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var contractid = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
var hrefa = "javascript\:SelectField\(\'\{808AEFE9-F68B-4F7B-AF62-C5B32723BBC1\}\'\,\'";
var hrefb = "'\)\;return\ false\;";

var optionline = "<option value='"+hrefa+""+contractid+""+hrefb+"'>otherstuff</option>";
```

The final product is supposed to look like this:

```
javascript:SelectField('{808AEFE9-F68B-4F7B-AF62-C5B32723BBC1}','133');return false;
```

but it always comes out like this:

```
false;'="" {808aefe9-f68b-4f7b-af62-c5b32723bbc1}','115');return="" value="javascript:SelectField("
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea. What are you trying to achieve by storing a javascript URL in the value attribute of an option?

Comment: You're probably right... I have the `<select onchange="window.open(this.value,'_self','');">` so when an option is selected it will perform that JavaScript action. I don't think it will work in the end, though.

Comment: You should be able to make your code significantly more maintainable and readable by attaching the change handler using e.g. http://api.jquery.com/change/ instead of using inline events in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it more complex than it needs to be. Just reverse the quotes in the output.

```
var contractid = $(this).attr("ows_ID"),
    hrefa = "javascript:SelectField('{808AEFE9-F68B-4F7B-AF62-C5B32723BBC1}','",
    hrefb = "');return false;",
    optionline = '<option value="' + hrefa + contractid + hrefb + '">otherstuff</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've played around on jsfiddle now.

This looks correct to me?

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7BP7/3/